# Can this Patch Panel be used for data?

Tags: networking

I don't know much about networking. I just bought a house which has this panel:

http://www.snapav.com/p-678-wp-mod-rj45-tel1x12.aspx

And all the rooms are terminated with a CAT-5 or CAT-6 jack. My question is:  it says it is for telephone, but am I able to use this panel and hook it up to my cable modem or router to have hard line access in all the other room?  Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, this is a telephone distribution panel.  It does not appear to be suitable for Ethernet.  If you already have the cat-5 wired in the box with something like [this](http://www.levitonproducts.com/catalog/dept_id_852/model_47605-C5B.htm), then you could patch your phone circuits to the jacks.  To use the lines this way they would need to be wired using EIA-568A rather than EIA-568B.  You would then use patch cables to link the lines to provide phone or Ethernet service.  Ethernet service would need a router.